# Visual Basic Json.net Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException error

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, instagram, screen-scraping

So I have recently started learning Visual Basic and was testing out parsing HTML data just for a bit of fun. When I came into some JSON so I downloaded the newton-soft pack and started learning how it worked. I started off simply trying to get the URL for any users Instagram page but came into an error which I can't seem to solve and with me being new to VB I thought it was best to ask for some help rather than frazzle my mind.

Here is the code:

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim user As String = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim html = "https://www.instagram.com/" + user
        Console.WriteLine(html)
        Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
        Dim htmlDoc = web.Load(html)
        For Each node As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script[@type='text/javascript']")
            If node.InnerHtml.Contains("profile_pic_url_hd") Then 'Makes sure the correct javascript code is used.
                Dim json = node.InnerHtml.Substring(21, node.InnerHtml.Length - 21) 'Deletes the non Json code in the javascript.
                Dim m As User = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of User)(json) 'Error is here
                Dim picture As String = m.profile_pic_url_hd
                Console.WriteLine(picture)
                Console.ReadLine()
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Could not find correct code! Possibly because the username doesn't exist")
            End If
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    End Sub

    Public Class User
        Public Property biography As String
        Public Property blocked_by_viewer As Boolean
        Public Property country_block As Boolean
        Public Property external_url As Object
        Public Property external_url_linkshimmed As Object
        Public Property followed_by As Integer
        Public Property followed_by_viewer As Boolean
        Public Property follows As Integer
        Public Property follows_viewer As Boolean
        Public Property full_name As String
        Public Property has_blocked_viewer As Boolean
        Public Property has_requested_viewer As Boolean
        Public Property id As String
        Public Property is_private As Boolean
        Public Property is_verified As Boolean
        Public Property profile_pic_url As String
        Public Property profile_pic_url_hd As String
        Public Property requested_by_viewer As Boolean
        Public Property username As String
        Public Property connected_fb_page As Object
        Public Property media As Object
    End Class
End Module
```

So I get the error on this line:

```
Dim m As User = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of User)(json)
```

Saying: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ;. Path '', line 1, position 3220.'
The position number always changes. But I am not sure why this is occurring.

Any help I am thankful for!

Edit:
The Json is different for everybodies instagram account but as an example here is Fifa's Json:
https://pastebin.com/J3U0uz4S

Comment: It would help to post the json - also `As Object` looks suspicious.  That usually means a Type that isnt represented in the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here.

The main problem is that your JSON string ends with a semicolon character (`;`) after the final closing brace, which is not valid JSON.  (See [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/).)  The parser is obviously not expecting this, so it is throwing an exception telling you that there is additional text (the semicolon) after the end of JSON the content.  So you need to strip off this extra character before deserializing.

```
json = json.TrimEnd(";")
```

Once you fix that, the second issue is that your model does not match the JSON.  It looks like you are attempting to deserialize just the `user` data, but that data is nested several levels down in the JSON.  You need classes to represent these outer layers.  You don't necessarily need to add every single property at each level--just the ones you are interested in--but you do need all the levels represented from the root on down to the target object in order to deserialize it properly.

By the way, Visual Studio has feature which can generate classes for you from a  JSON sample.  Just copy your JSON to the clipboard and select `Paste JSON As Classes` from the `Edit -> Paste Special` menu.  Note this tool is not foolproof; the generated classes sometimes need some manual corrections.  In particular, the tool generates array properties incorrectly.  But, it can give you a big head start when you are working with a complicated JSON structure.

Below is the *minimum* class structure that you would need to deserialize the basic `user` data from your JSON.  (Note that I left out the `media` property; you will need to define some more classes if you want to get that data.)

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property entry_data As Entry_Data
End Class

Public Class Entry_Data
    Public Property ProfilePage As List(Of Profilepage) 
End Class

Public Class Profilepage
    Public Property user As User
End Class

Public Class User
    Public Property biography As String
    Public Property blocked_by_viewer As Boolean
    Public Property country_block As Boolean
    Public Property external_url As String
    Public Property external_url_linkshimmed As String
    Public Property followed_by As Followed_By
    Public Property followed_by_viewer As Boolean
    Public Property follows As Follows
    Public Property follows_viewer As Boolean
    Public Property full_name As String
    Public Property has_blocked_viewer As Boolean
    Public Property has_requested_viewer As Boolean
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property is_private As Boolean
    Public Property is_verified As Boolean
    Public Property profile_pic_url As String
    Public Property profile_pic_url_hd As String
    Public Property requested_by_viewer As Boolean
    Public Property username As String
    Public Property connected_fb_page As Object
End Class

Public Class Followed_By
    Public Property count As Integer
End Class

Public Class Follows
    Public Property count As Integer
End Class
```

Once you have that, you can deserialize and fetch the profile picture like this:

```
' Deserialize into the Rootobject class
Dim root As Rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(json)

' Drill down to get the profile pic
Dim picture As String = root.entry_data.ProfilePage(0).user.profile_pic_url_hd
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dNLXDx

Comment: Thank you, this was incredibly helpful and just what I  was looking for. I now have a greater understanding for future ventures.

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.